# AjAX calls and setInterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination.
I use

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var pageNum = 1;
$(".paginationing").click(function(){
pageNum = $(this).attr("id");
});


    setInterval("ajaxd("+pageNum+")",5000);

});

function ajaxd(pageNum) { 


    var thisuser = $("#thisusern").text();
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "newstitle.php",
   data: "user="+thisuser+"&page="+pageNum,
   success: function(msg){
     $("#edix").html(msg);
   }
 });
}
```

To send the page number.But it sends only page number 1 ,even I click on the page number.
Where's the bug?How can I implement AJAX pagination with setInterval to call the page every 5 seconds?

Comment: Why are you using setInterval to do the pagination why can you invoke the pagination call in the click event handler?

Comment: I use setInterval to call the page every 5 seconds.It's not involved with the pagination.I want to have AJAX pagination but also to call newstitle.php every 5 seconds(but with the chosen page number.).In newstitle.php I have code that outputs results according to page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why are you using setInterval to paginate instead of calling the ajaxd function in the click event handler.
I would do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageNum = 1;
    $(".paginationing").click(function() {
                pageNum = $(this).attr("id");
                ajaxd(pageNum);
    });
});

function ajaxd(pgNo) {
        var thisuser = $("#thisusern").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "newstitle.php",
        data: "user=" + thisuser + "&page=" + pgNo,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#edix").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

If you still want to use the setInterval try this:

```
   var pageNum = 1;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".paginationing").click(function() {
            pageNum = $(this).attr("id");
        });
        setInterval(ajaxd, 5000);
    });

    function ajaxd() {
            var pgNo = pageNum;
        var thisuser = $("#thisusern").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "newstitle.php",
            data: "user=" + thisuser + "&page=" + pgNo,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#edix").html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

**P.S:**
Also note that a valid id for a HTML element should not start with a number but I think you are relying on that. I would rather advice you to generate the id something like "pg-n" where n is the number and in the click event you can get the page number using

```
pageNum = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

Comment: Thank You for the advice.I changed my code.
The second code gives me error "pageNum is not defined" ,when I click on the page numbers it also gives that error.